# Flush Logcat in androidapp

Tags: android, logcat

I can’t figure out how to flush the Logcat on my Application. Code below

Saving Logcat into File: (this works)

```
File File_logcat = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "log.txt");
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "logcat -f " + File_logcat.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After that save I flush the Logcat with: (this doesn't work)

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "logcat --clear"); //Also tested -c or -b all –c
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I’ve searched for a solution on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) which says “logcat -b all –c” (or even –c) would flush it but none of them  succeed.

Did I miss something?

Comment: This should be possibly only on a rooted device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CommonsWare.
I just discovered that both code snippets work on a **rooted** mobile device. So it seems like you can't flush it without permission.